# matplotlib: using a colormap to color table-cell background

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe, and i want to plot it as matplotlib table. So far i have that part working with following code:

```
import numpy as np
randn = np.random.randn
from pandas import *

idx = Index(arange(1,11))
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 5), index=idx, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
vals = np.around(df.values,2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=True, xticks=[], yticks=[])

the_table=plt.table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=df.index, colLabels=df.columns, 
                    colWidths = [0.03]*vals.shape[1], loc='center')

table_props = the_table.properties()
table_cells = table_props['child_artists']

clm = cm.hot(vals)

for cell in table_cells: 
    cell.set_height(0.04)
    # now i would like to set the backgroundcolor of the cell
```

At the end of this i would like to set the background-color of the cell according to the colormap - but how do i look it up in the clm array without an index?

Another question: can i somehow pass a format string to the table, so that it formats the text to 2 decimal places?

Any hints appreciated,
Andy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`plt.Normalize()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) to normalize your data, and the pass the normalized data to a [`Colormap` object](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html), for example [`plt.cm.hot()`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

[`plt.table()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html) has an argument `cellColours`, which will be used to set the cells' background color accordingly.

Because `cm.hot` maps black to the minimal value, I increased the value range when creating the normalization object.

Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
randn = np.random.randn
from pandas import *

idx = Index(np.arange(1,11))
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 5), index=idx, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
vals = np.around(df.values,2)
norm = plt.Normalize(vals.min()-1, vals.max()+1)
colours = plt.cm.hot(normal(vals))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=True, xticks=[], yticks=[])

the_table=plt.table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=df.index, colLabels=df.columns, 
                    colWidths = [0.03]*vals.shape[1], loc='center', 
                    cellColours=colours)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `normal(vals)` be replaced with `norm(vals)`?

Answer (score 0):

The Andy's code working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# sudo apt-get install python-pandas
# sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
# 
# python teste.py

from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import cm

import numpy

from pandas import *

idx = Index(numpy.arange(1, 11))

df = DataFrame(
        numpy.random.randn(10, 5),
        index=idx,
        columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    )

vals = numpy.around(df.values, 2)

normal = pyplot.normalize(vals.min()-1, vals.max()+1)

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(15, 8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=True, xticks=[], yticks=[])

the_table = pyplot.table(
                cellText=vals,
                rowLabels=df.index,
                colLabels=df.columns, 
                colWidths = [0.03]*vals.shape[1],
                loc='center', 
                cellColours=pyplot.cm.hot(normal(vals))
            )

pyplot.show()
```